# Why is Safari using and displaying the wrong CSS class in dev tools?

Tags: css, angular, sass, safari

I'm using plain old `ng serve` with Angular 10/Sass and getting this crazy behavior in Safari where it is using and displaying the wrong class. That is to say, a class that exists in my stylesheet but **is not** the class on the element.

In the image below, you can see that my `div` on the left has the `fill` class and that on the right, what is displayed is the `fill-view-height` class - an entirely different class in my stylesheet which is nowhere in the hierarchy of this element:

[image]

Now in this next image is what it looks like in Chrome (pictured) and Firefox (not pictured).

[image]

And finally, here is an image of what it looks like in Safari when I remove the `fill` class from the left using the inspector. You can see that now `fill-view-height` is gone from the right sidebar:

[image]

`fill-view-height` directly follows `fill` in my site-level stylesheet, but I rearranged the order and it didn't make a difference. I also renamed `fill` to be something completely different, but it didn't make a difference. It still worked in Chrome/Firefox and did not work in Safari. I also re-ran `ng serve` and tried a private window. I would love some insight into the madness that I'm witnessing or tips on how I might track down the problem.